# What's the best Python string split approach?

Tags: python, split, pep

I am refactoring some python code and have noticed the original creator has been calling the split method each time they need an element from the resulting split list, rather than storing the split result as a variable.

I am wondering if there is any performance benefit between the two options, or if one is more pythonic than the other?

e.g. what I would've done

```
words = sentence.split(" ")
first_word = words[0]
second_word = words[1]
```

Vs what they have done

```
first_word = sentence.split(" ")[0]
second_word = sentence.split(" ")[1]
```

Comment: `first_word, second_word, *_ = sentence.split(" ")`? That avoids the risk of the error you made: repeating the same index. There's certainly no point splitting the string twice.

Comment: Aha great point! I've corrected the mistake, but I do agree with not splitting multiple times. My thoughts were that surely it is marginally less efficient too?

Comment: The original code will (roughly) use 2 times more CPU

Answer (score 3):

If you want to optimize, limit the split to 2 occurences, and only keep the first 2 items:

```
first_word, second_word = sentence.split(' ', maxsplit=2)[:2]
```

This way you only have to split once, and don't need to store the intermediate in memory.

If then sentence is small:

```
first_word, second_word, _ = sentence.split(' ', maxsplit=2)
```

##### further optimization for long sentences

If you want to optimize further, you need to avoid reading the whole string.

For this you need to get the index of the first 2 blank spaces and slice your string:

```
i = sentence.index(' ')
j = sentence.index(' ', i+1)
first_word, second_word = sentence[:i], sentence[i+1:j]
```

A test on a 100k words sentence (`sentence = ' '.join(['abc']*100000)`) shows a 30 times speedup compared to `split`. This approach is however not more efficient (or even less efficient) on small strings.

Comment: If you really want to optimize, it's better to avoid slicing: `first_word, second_word, _ = sentence.split(' ', maxsplit=2)`

Comment: @Expurple I am not sure, this also sets a new variable which consumes memory/garbage collection. A quick test tells me there is minimal time difference for large lists. If one is sure the sentence will be **small**, then I agree with you ;)

Comment: That object with the remaining sentence is created by `.split` in both cases, anyway. With my solution, it's just (probably?) garbage collected a bit later, because it needs to outlive the `_` binding.

Comment: @Expurple I added a better approach for long sentences

Comment: Yeah, looks good, this approach doesn't needlessly copy the end of the sentence to a new string.

Answer (score 0):

@mozway's answer + comments cover the performance side very well, it should probably be the accepted answer.

You also wondered about the "more pythonic" way, so I'll add my two cents on that.

In my opinion, the easiest to read option is actually the original one, because it calls the words `words`. It doesn't even require the reader to understand what exactly `sentence.split(" ")` is doing :)

If you also want performace, the next best bet is my proposed solution:

```py
first_word, second_word, _ = sentence.split(' ', maxsplit=2)
```

It's both pretty pefrormant (splits just once and doesn't split unnecessary words at the and) and pretty clear about what it does: takes the first 2 words and discards the rest. It's also a one-liner :)